# Ionic & video.js on iOS silent switch with video

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, video.js

In my Ionic app on iOS (tested on several iOS versions and devices) the ringer silent switch is muting video playback.

Is this a known issue with iOS or Ionic or video.js and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks